# Как отобразить все значения в одном окне MSGBOX в vba word?

Tags: алгоритм

```
sab()
    dim x0,xn,dx,x,a,b,c,p,qas single
    x0 = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення x0="))
    xn = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення xn="))
    dx = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення dx="))
    a = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення a="))
    b = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення b="))
    c = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення c="))
    q = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення q="))
    p = CSng(InputBox("Введіть значення p="))
    x = x0
    While x <= xn
    If x > 4 And x < 15 Then
    If p = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Помилка на 0 ділити не можна")
    GoTo 1
    Else
    y = Cos(x) - Sin(q / p) - (1 * Tan(x))
    MsgBox ("y=" + Str(y) + " При значенні x=" + Str(x) + "   За формулою1")
    End If
    Else
    If x > 15 Then
    If c = 0 Then
    MsgBox ("Помилка на 0 ділити не можна")
    GoTo 1
    Else
    y = (a * (1 / Tan(x)) + b * Cos(x) ^ (1 / 2)) / c
    MsgBox ("y=" + Str(y) + " При значенні x=" + Str(x) + "   За формулою2")
    End If
    Else
    y = Sqr((a * Tan(x))) - b * (Log(x + 4 * a)) + c
    MsgBox ("y=" + Str(y) + " При значенні x=" + Str(x) + "   За формулою 3")
    End If
    End If
    x = x + dx
    Wend
    1:
End Sub
```

Comment: очень жаль. на код попыток бы посмотреть...

Comment: вот я  скинул ............

Comment: Код в виде текста было бы удобнее копировать и запускать у себя

Comment: какой результат должен быть в итоге?

Comment: (y=) в одном окне должно вивести мне 5 значений

Comment: результат формул неважен

Comment: можно просто в одну строку записать все ответы а потом вывести её

Comment: x (-10:10)/////

Answer (score 0):

```
' Можно объявить строку и в ней накапливать значения
Dim Result as String

Result = ""
While x <= xn
    If x > 4 And x < 15 Then
        If p = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Помилка на 0 ділити не можна")
            GoTo 1
        Else
            y = Cos(x) - Sin(q / p) - (1 * Tan(x))
            Result = Result & "y=" & Str(y) & " При значенні x=" & Str(x) & "   За формулою1"
        End If
    Else
        If x > 15 Then
            If c = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Помилка на 0 ділити не можна")
                GoTo 1
            Else
                y = (a * (1 / Tan(x)) + b * Cos(x) ^ (1 / 2)) / c
                Result = Result & "y=" & Str(y) & " При значенні x=" & Str(x) & "   За формулою2"
            End If
        Else
            y = Sqr((a * Tan(x))) - b * (Log(x + 4 * a)) + c
            Result = Result & "y=" & Str(y) & " При значенні x=" & Str(x) & "   За формулою 3"
        End If
    End If
    x = x + dx
Wend
1:
    MsgBox (Result)
```

Либо то же самое, но через массив:

```
Dim Result()
Dim Index as Integer
Index = 0

While x <= xn
    If x > 4 And x < 15 Then
        If p = 0 Then
            MsgBox ("Помилка на 0 ділити не можна")
            GoTo 1
        Else
            y = Cos(x) - Sin(q / p) - (1 * Tan(x))
            ReDim Preserve Result(Index)
            Result(Index) = "y=" & Str(y) & " При значенні x=" & Str(x) & "   За формулою1"
            Index = Index + 1
        End If
    Else
        If x > 15 Then
            If c = 0 Then
                MsgBox ("Помилка на 0 ділити не можна")
                GoTo 1
            Else
                ReDim Preserve Result(Index)
                y = (a * (1 / Tan(x)) + b * Cos(x) ^ (1 / 2)) / c
                Result(Index) = "y=" & Str(y) & " При значенні x=" & Str(x) & "   За формулою2"
                Index = Index + 1
            End If
        Else
            ReDim Preserve Result(Index)
            y = Sqr((a * Tan(x))) - b * (Log(x + 4 * a)) + c
            Result(Index) = "y=" & Str(y) & " При значенні x=" & Str(x) & "   За формулою 3"
            Index = Index + 1
        End If
    End If
    x = x + dx
Wend
1:
    MsgBox (Join(Result, Chr(13)))
```

Comment: спасибо, но не могу сделать чтоб каждый ответ был четко расположен на своих строках

Comment: можно использовать символ перевода на новую строку `Chr(13)`